# reposition a div tag after jquery animation

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i am using jquery to showing  a div tag and keep animation 10px from bottom
but whenever my function rising from iframe

its floating up it is not again repositioning

```
function Show_NotifyDiv() {
        $("#div_NotificationOuter").css({ "bottom": "2px", "right": "5px" });
        $("div_NotificationOuter").stop();
        $('#div_NotificationOuter').hide();
        $("#div_NotificationOuter").show(1000);
        $("#div_NotificationOuter").animate({ bottom: '+=10px' }, 4000);
}
```

Comment: You have a syntax error line 3 missing `#`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Parent Div is 100% height... Because you are using Bottom

Comment: $("div_NotificationOuter").stop();
replace it with $("#div_NotificationOuter").stop();